# What is a exact answer of $\sum x$ if $3x+16 \equiv x+1 \pmod {x-3} \qquad x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I was given a question:

> Find $\sum x$ if $$3x+16 \equiv x+1 \pmod {x-3} \qquad x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}.$$

I have solved it as follows:
$$2x+15\equiv 0\\$$ $$ \frac { 2x-6+21 }{ x-3 } =\frac { 2\left( x-3 \right) +21 }{ x-3 } =2+\frac { 21 }{ x-3 } $$
and here i think $x$ can be only $\\ \left\{ 4,6,10,24 \right\} $

Is that correct answer or i missed something  I always confuse definition of mod,can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $\;\sum x\;$ mean? Also, what is module in the real numbers?

Comment: Sum of all $x$  satisfying equation

Comment: Thank you, but what is that module there mean in $\;\Bbb R^+\;$ ?

Comment: I think here should be $  \mathbb{Z}  ^{+}  $,but the question is just i have written

Comment: I don't know what is the question but I think you should, otherwise how are we suppose to try to help you out if you don't understand what is written?

Comment: @Joanpemo, what if there are positive real numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35877/discussion-between-battani-and-joanpemo).

Comment: then I first need to know what does $\;\pmod{x-3}\;$ mean in the real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $3x + 16 \equiv 25$ but by definition we have $25 \equiv x + 1 \equiv 4 \pmod {x - 3}$. This means that $21 \equiv 0 \pmod {x - 3}$, that is, $x - 3 | 21$. We have $\tau (21) = 4$. We also have $$\sum (x - 3) = \sigma (21) = 32;$$ hence, $$\sum x = 32 + 3 \cdot \tau (21) = 32 + 3 \cdot 4 = 32 + 12 = 44.$$

Comment: is my answer correct?what is  $\sigma (21)$ in your solution?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct, although it lacks rigour. $\tau (n)$ means the number of positive integer divisors of $n$, and $\sigma (n)$ means the sum of positive integer divisors of $n$.

Comment: @Battani You're welcome.